# Tableau Custom SQL + Left Joins (Excel)

Tags: csv, left-join, tableau-api

I'm working with a custom SQL Query + 3 CSV Left Joins. However, each time I initialize the workbook it doesn't seem to store those file locations and I have to re-join the data each time.

Is there a way to prevent this, without using an extract? The file is to be used as the basis for a monthly report, which then gets extracted after update.

[image]

Comment: where do you store your csv files? do you change the path? what OS and Tableau version are you using?

Comment: The files are local. Path hasn't changed. I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise - SP1. Tableau v10.0

Comment: that's odd. did you change the file names or structure? what happens if you click `Refresh` in the `Data` pane?

Comment: Agreed it is odd. If i try to refresh it asks to repoint the data source, despite it not having changed.